# C# Enum.ToString() with complete name

Tags: c#, enums, tostring

I am searching a solution to get the complete String of an enum.

Example:

```
Public Enum Color
{
    Red = 1,
    Blue = 2
}
Color color = Color.Red;

// This will always get "Red" but I need "Color.Red"
string colorString = color.ToString();

// I know that this is what I need:
colorString = Color.Red.ToString();
```

So is there a solution?

Comment: `Color.Red.ToString()` returns `Red` as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string GetFullName(this Enum myEnum)
    {
      return string.Format("{0}.{1}", myEnum.GetType().Name, myEnum.ToString());
    }
}
```

usage:

```
Color color = Color.Red;
string fullName = color.GetFullName();
```

Note: I think `GetType().Name` is better that `GetType().FullName`

Comment: Good one ! I Use this !!

Comment: An update to the syntax would be: `return $"{myEnum.GetType().Name}.{myEnum}";`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        Color color = Color.Red;

        string colorString = color.GetType().Name + "." + Enum.GetName(typeof(Color), color);
```

Comment: Am extremely sorry. `I thought Color is System.Drawing.Color`

Answer (score 1):

Fast variant that works for every enum

```
public static class EnumUtil<TEnum> where TEnum : struct
{
    public static readonly Dictionary<TEnum, string> _cache;

    static EnumUtil()
    {
        _cache = Enum
            .GetValues(typeof(TEnum))
            .Cast<TEnum>()
            .ToDictionary(x => x, x => string.Format("{0}.{1}", typeof(TEnum).Name, x));
    }

    public static string AsString(TEnum value)
    {
        return _cache[value];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this is the best way, but it works:

```
string colorString = string.Format("{0}.{1}", color.GetType().FullName, color.ToString())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 colorString = color.GetType().Name + "." + color.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use extension methods.

```
public static class EnumExtension
{
    public static string ToCompleteName(this Color c)
    {
        return "Color." + c.ToString();
    }
}
```

Now method below will return "Color.Red".

```
color.ToCompleteName();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx