# Tuple or multi-key dictionary?

Tags: c#

I have a number of enums used for errors, eg:

```
public enum LoginError
{
    None = 0,
    InvalidUsername,
    InvalidPassword,
}

public enum CustomerError
{
    None = 0,
    NameRequired,
    SurnameRequired,
}
```

For each enum, I would like to have the description stored in a list, so that I would be able to do something like this:

```
string desc = errorList(typeof(LoginError), myError.LoginError); //or something similar
```

Would it work if I use a multi-key dictionary or a tuple? Any examples that show how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `Dictionary<Tuple<Type,int>,string>`?

Comment: Since these are two distinct error types with distinct enums, I would create two dictionaries.

Comment: If you by "description" mean their textual representation, you should not store that in a separate list. You can always retrieve that text by using Enum.GetName(myenum.GetType(),myenum);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a enums [full name string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890763/c-sharp-enum-tostring-with-complete-name) as a key.

```
Dictionary<string,string> map;

private string GetEnumName(Enum _enum)
{
    return string.Format("{0}.{1}", _enum.GetType().Name, _enum.ToString());
}

void RegisterMapping(Enum @enum, string displayName)
{
    var enumName= GetEnumName(@enum);
    map.Add(enumName, displayName);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this will work for you,

```
public enum LoginError
        {
            None = 0,
            InvalidUsername,
            InvalidPassword,
        }

        public enum CustomerError
        {
            None = 0,
            NameRequired,
            SurnameRequired,
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<Enum, string> myErrorDictionary = new Dictionary<Enum, string>();

            myErrorDictionary.Add(LoginError.None, "This is None from Login Error");
            myErrorDictionary.Add(LoginError.InvalidUsername, "Invalid username");
            myErrorDictionary.Add(LoginError.InvalidPassword, "Invalid Password");

            myErrorDictionary.Add(CustomerError.None, "This is None from Custom Error");
            myErrorDictionary.Add(CustomerError.NameRequired, "Name Required");
            myErrorDictionary.Add(CustomerError.SurnameRequired, "Surname Required");

            Console.WriteLine(myErrorDictionary[LoginError.None]);
            Console.WriteLine(myErrorDictionary[CustomerError.None]);

            Console.Read();
        }
```

Comment: I am quite surprised that this works and I learned something new today. The keys are not just the integral values of the enums (which overlap) but instead boxed enum values which are considered not equal even though the underlying enum values are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at

> MultiValueDictionary

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/08/05/multidictionary-becomes-multivaluedictionary.aspx